# Getting Error While Running bash script scripts/code.sh

Tags: visual-studio-code, open-source

I am new to vscode repo.
I was trying to clone and run the vscode repo on my local desktop.

I was following their readme file instructions and followed below steps.

yarn install runs perfectly .
But while running bash scripts/code.sh
I am getting this issue.
Please help me out !
 `[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/ppandey/vscode/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js'] { errno: -2, code: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'open', path: '/Users/ppandey/vscode/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js', phase: 'loading', moduleId: 'vs/code/electron-main/main', neededBy: [ '===anonymous1===' ] }`

Comment: what is this "scripts/code.sh" that you are referring to? something you wrote yourself? Something that comes with VS Code?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue you're facing may be related to the absence of Yarn in your Node Version Manager (nvm) environment. When you open another terminal tab to execute **scripts/code.sh**, it could potentially switch to your default Node.js version managed by nvm, which might lack Yarn. To resolve this, follow these steps:

1. Ensure that you are using the correct Node.js version specified in your project's .nvmrc file or the default version set in nvm by running:

   ```
   nvm use
   ```

   This command will activate the Node.js version appropriate for your project. Confirm that Yarn is installed in this specific Node.js instance.
2. If Yarn is not installed, you can install it using npm:

   ```
   npm install --global yarn
   ```

   After successfully installing Yarn, you should be able to execute both yarn install and scripts/code.sh within the vscode repository without encountering any issues.

This error typically occurs when there is a mismatch in Node.js and package manager versions across different terminal tabs or when required packages are missing. These steps should help you resolve the issue and get the vscode repository running smoothly on your local machine.

feel free to ask for more assistance.