# Error when building vscode in container using "bash script/code.sh"

Tags: bash, docker, electron, vscode-remote, vscode-devcontainer

I am trying to build "vscode" using container and was referring to the [documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/.devcontainer/README.md#try-it).

But I am stuck on the `bash script/code.sh` command.
It is giving me the following error:

```
[3126:1009/110830.267788:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[3126:1009/110830.268002:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[3126:1009/110830.268031:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[3126:1009/110830.268059:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[3126:1009/110830.458678:WARNING:bluez_dbus_manager.cc(247)] Floss manager not present, cannot set Floss enable/disable.
[3126:1009/110830.458793:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(590)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.portal.Settings.Read: object_path= /org/freedesktop/portal/desktop: unknown error type: 
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspaces/vscode/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/workspaces/vscode/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js',
  phase: 'loading',
  moduleId: 'vs/code/electron-main/main',
  neededBy: [ '===anonymous1===' ]
}
[3277:1009/110830.933691:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(186)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[3341:1009/110831.225419:WARNING:sandbox_linux.cc(393)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[3341:1009/110831.310201:WARNING:gpu_memory_buffer_support_x11.cc(49)] dri3 extension not supported.
```

I tried to look up the error and it said to [update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76643204/getting-error-while-running-bash-script-scripts-code-sh) the node and yarn. I did the update but the error was still there